# App Script Google Error Token Delete Gmail

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail, token, gmail-api

I'm trying to create a script to delete emails and I'm getting a failure in the token, I don't know if I'm using a wrong token or I have another bug.

I have created a project with a key and this is the key I have used in the script as token.

```
function deleteEMail() {
 var mymail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 var mylabel = "mytest";
 var permanentlyRemoveMyLabel = true;
 var pageToken ="*****************************************";

 do {
   var threadList = Gmail.Users.Threads.list('me', {
     q: 'subject:' + mylabel,
     pageToken: pageToken
 });

 if (threadList.threads && threadList.threads.length > 0) {
  threadList.threads.forEach(function(thread) {
    Logger.log('id: %s snippet: %s', thread.id, thread.snippet);
    if (permanentlyRemoveMyLabel) {
      Gmail.Users.Threads.remove(mymail, thread.id);
      Logger.log('id: %s snippet: %s REMOVED', thread.id, thread.snippet);
     }
   });
 }
 pageToken = threadList.nextPageToken;
} while (pageToken);
```

}

Comment: About your reply of `Si quieres hablamos en español, intento realizar un script que me borre algunos de los correos y me da el error del token. no se si el token que le tengo puesto es el adecuado o deba buscar otro en otro sitio. Realicé un proyecto vacío y genere una clave. `.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. So I think that in this case, I cannot support you. Because of my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. By this, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.